# Javascript form function submit not auto submitting

Tags: javascript

Javascript function ASP `<body onload="form1.submit();">` is not submitting the form below once the page have loaded.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var count = 20;
            $.extend($.wordStats.stopWords, {'retrieved': true, '2007': true});
            $.wordStats.computeTopWords(count);
   var msgsubmit = '<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />'
   var msgform = '<html><body onload="form1.submit();"><form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="get_page_2.asp">\n'
            var msg = 'Keywords: <textarea name="g_seo_no_keywords" id="g_seo_no_keywords" cols="120" rows="3">';
   var msgend = '</textarea>\n';
   var msgg_seo_no_title = '<input type="text" name="g_seo_no_title" id="g_seo_no_title" value="title" />'
   var msgg_seo_no_title_count = '<input type="text" name="g_seo_no_title_count" id="g_seo_no_title_count" value="0" />'
   var msgg_seo_no_keywords_count = '<input type="text" name="g_seo_no_keywords_count" id="g_seo_no_keywords_count" value="0" />'
   var msgg_page_no = '<input type="text" name="g_page_no" id="g_page_no" value="<%=(Request.Form("g_page_no"))%>" />'
   var msgg_page_site = '<input type="text" name="g_page_site" id="g_page_site" value="<%= Request.Form("g_page_site") %>" />'
   var msgg_page_url = '<input type="text" name="g_page_url" id="g_page_url" value="<%= Request.Form("g_page_url") %>" />'
   var msgcounttext = 'Word Count: <input type="text" name="g_seo_no_description_count" id="g_seo_no_description_count" value="<%= counttext %>" />\n';
   var msgg_seo_no_textcount = 'Word Count: <input type="text" name="g_seo_no_textcount" id="g_seo_no_textcount" value="<%= counttext %>" />\n';
   var msgcounttext1 = '<textarea name="g_seo_no_description" id="g_seo_no_description" cols="120" rows="15"><%=completehtml%></textarea>\n'
            for(var i = 0, j = $.wordStats.topWords.length; i < j && i <= count; i++) {
               msg += $.wordStats.topWords[i].substring(1) + ', ';
            }
   var msgformend ='</form></body></html>\n'
            document.write(msgform)+document.write(msg)+document.write(msgend)+document.write(msgg_page_no)+document.write(msgg_page_site)+document.write(msgg_page_url)+document.write(msgg_seo_no_textcount)+document.write(msgg_seo_no_title)+document.write(msgg_seo_no_title_count)+document.write(msgg_seo_no_keywords_count)+document.write(msgcounttext)+document.write(msgsubmit)+document.write(msgcounttext1)+document.write(msgformend);
            $.wordStats.clear();
        });
        </script>
```

Hi There I am hoping that someone can help me to find the solution why this form is not getting submitted when the page loads.

How would I go about to submit this page? It is supposed to be an autosubmit

Thanks

Comment: just curious... do you have to make the page like this? this seems **massively convoluted** if you just want to submit a form to the server.

Comment: Do you absolutely need to create the markup via js?

Comment: Hi Guys - The document write is the problem - I think - is there another way that I can pass the document.write to the page or a form on the page? instead of creating a new "js" page? I have done it before but for some reason I cannot remember how I did it...

Comment: Ugh, serious escaping problems here. Imagine what a `'`, `"` or `<` would do in those strings. Don't stuff strings together like this, you're making an unmaintainable, XSS-vulnerability-ridden mess.

Comment: Hi Bobince I am using a regex prior to it that strippes out everything non text...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `document.form1.submit()` or `document.forms.form1.submit()` instead

Comment: Hi Crayon thanks for the tip, I have tried it but it does not seem to work it feels like the document.write part is creating a second page (on the same page) but disabling (scripts) to render on the page... not sure if it makes sense..

Comment: Ah ha! - if you are running this as part of code on an *existing* page then it will not work! the onload event has already occurred.

Comment: Hi Crayon I have used the example that you have provided in the last part of the code document.write(msgform)+document.write(msg)+document.write(msgend) I have added the document.form1.submit() there and now it works, instead of adding it in the <body onload="form1.submit();"> - Thanks for everybody's input it helped me solve this problem in under 30 minutes :-) :-)

Answer (score 0):

**After this** line

```
    $.wordStats.clear();
```

try

```
$("#form1").submit();
```

Comment: Hi JapanPro tried it but it does not seem to work - please see my answer to Crayon Below...